# Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop: on restart, some services do not bind to public IP, only localhost

Tags: networking, server, 22.04

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop on which I want to run public services (postgreSQL, redis, etc.) to access from other hosts. I configured each service to bind (listen) to the static IP 192.168.1.xxx as well as localhost, started them, and they work.

When I restart the computer, these services are not listening on 192.168.1.xxx, only on localhost/127.0.0.1. When I restart the service, it binds to all addresses. No changes. No Firewall. *SSH does connect via the IP address.* Here is a paste of the Redis example run locally immediately after a reboot.

```
% sudo ufw status                                                                                                 
Status: inactive

% redis-cli -h 192.168.1.200
Could not connect to Redis at 192.168.1.200:6379: Connection refused
not connected>

% redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1:6379>

% redis-cli -h localhost
localhost:6379>

% sudo lsof -i :6379
COMMAND    PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
redis-ser 3004 redis    6u  IPv4  35436      0t0  TCP localhost:redis (LISTEN)
redis-ser 3004 redis    7u  IPv6  35437      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:redis (LISTEN)

% sudo service redis-server restart

% sudo lsof -i :6379
COMMAND     PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
redis-ser 14396 redis    6u  IPv4  67757      0t0  TCP localhost:redis (LISTEN)
redis-ser 14396 redis    7u  IPv6  67758      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:redis (LISTEN)
redis-ser 14396 redis    8u  IPv4  67759      0t0  TCP server:redis (LISTEN)

% redis-cli -h 192.168.1.200
192.168.1.200:6379>
```

What would be preventing the services from binding to public IP addresses during boot? Anthing to do with it being a desktop install? Thank you in advance for you time!

Comment: Watch your system start up, discover its hardware, and _start the services_ with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who posted suggestions. It supported my hunch that the network was not yet ready when the service started. I was able to confirm:

- A super-clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop VM had the same issue (services did not bind to public IP on restart, only loopback addresses).
- A clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 Server worked as expected (services started listening to the given IP addresses).
- It seems the start-up differs for Server and Desktop. Perhaps the network is configured after/within the GUI Desktop?
- This link about systemd has more in depth information: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/cause-a-script-to-execute-after-networking-has-started#126146
- The above link spoke of binding with a wildcard address (* or 0.0.0.0) instead of the literal public static IP. **This works!** It may not be what you want if you have multiple network interfaces though...but then you likely won't use Desktop in that case.
- A complete solution would involve learning systemd and debugging start-up.

Answer (score 0):

The service might start before the network interface is fully ready and configured that make the service only bind with `localhost` instead of the IP you want.

You can do these things to check if it is fully ready and configured before the service start, first configure your `systemd` service file to be dependant on the network being up by adding this line to the `[Unit]` section `After=network-online.target`. You can also modify `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` to include your static IP address, for example

```
DNS=192.168.1.1
Domains=example.com
```

You can also use the traditional network configuration method, edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and set `managed=false` then, configure your network interface in the /etc/network/`interfaces` file. Also in the `systemd` service file you could delay the start of the service with this:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30
ExecStart=/usr/bin/postgresql
```